# Changing Javascript code To jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

Hello everyone I hope all doing great!
I am very good at ***jQuery*** but I dont know pure ***Javascript*** a lot

Can you guys please convert this Javascript script to jQuery?
Or show me a way to convert it?

```js
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var last_data;
function get_new_message(){
    if(window.EventSource){
        source = new EventSource("server.php");
        source.addEventListener("message", function(event){
            if(event.data != last_data && event.data != ""){
                document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML += event.data+"<hr>";
            }
            last_data = event.data;
        });
    } else {
        alert("event source does not work in this browser, author a fallback technology");
        // Program Ajax Polling version here or another fallback technology like flash
    }
}
get_new_message();
```

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: This is where you start : http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/javascript

Comment: Thank you very much Sir, I have lots of tutorials but i dont like javascript.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand jQuery then.

Comment: Sir,  I said I don't know advance and pure javascript I know basic Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try [$.EventSource](https://github.com/rwaldron/jquery.eventsource)

Something like:

```
$.eventsource({
    url: "server.php",
    message: function(data) {
      // do something with data
    }
});
```